# Not sure I understand dependancy between 2 django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I am struggling to understand django models relationship.

I have this arborescence:

A train have cars, and those cars are divided into parts. Then those parts all contains different references.
Like, for exemple, all the trains have the 6 cars, and the cars 6 parts. Each part have x reference to be associated.

I would like to use all of them in a template later on, where the user can select the train, the car and the part he worked on, then generate a table from his selections with only the references associated to the parts he selected.
It should update the train and the car (I'm trying to update a stock of elements for a company)

I dont really understand which model field give to each of them. After checking the doc, Ive done something like this but i am not convinced:

```
class Train(Car):
    train = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=100)
    selected = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Car(Part):
    car = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=100)
    selected = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Part(Reference):
    part = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=100)
    selected = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Reference(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key='True', max_length=100)
    selected = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference
```

Can someone please help me understand this so I can do well ? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1-)if you add abstract = True in your Model Meta class, your class doesn't created on database as a table. If you store data for any class, you mustn't define abstract = True.

2-)For relations, you can use models.ForeignKey . If you add a class into brackets of another class, it names: inheritance.(You can think like parent-child relation). In database management, we can use foreignkey for one-to-many relationship.

3-)In Django ORM, id field automatically generated. So you don't need to define id field.

If I understand correctly, also you want to store parts of user's selected.

So, your model can be like that:

```
class Train(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) # I think you want to save name of train

class Car(models.Model):
    train = models.ForeignKey(Train,on_delete=models.Cascade)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Part(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car,on_delete=models.Cascade)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Reference(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part,on_delete=models.Cascade)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference

#addtional table for storing user's references
 class UserReference(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.Cascade)
    reference = models.ForeignKey(Reference,on_delete=models.Cascade)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

With this definitions, you can store user's definition on UserReference table. And with Django Orm, you can access train object from UserReferenceObject.

```
#user_reference: UserReference object like that result of UserReference.objects.first()
user_reference.reference.part.car.train.name
```

Comment: Hello Kamil, thank you so much for your answer! Ok. I understand! About UserReference, it will get the reference selected for the specific car and train right? I was so far from this result!!

Comment: I realized that I forgot added user field to UserReference, sorry. For your quetion, actually yes, UserReference stores var and train reference.

Comment: In fact This solution doesnt work . I have many different trains, but they all have the same cars names, and the cars have the same parts, but the parts have different references. How could I do ?